# Nginx FastCGI for jpg + gif + png caching

Tags: php, caching, nginx, fastcgi

Looking at how nginx-fastCGI can be used for caching in a *php* app, I see the following

```
location ~ ^(.+\.php)(.*)$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info       ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /path/to/php$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
}
```

If this were a python app, life would be much simpler, but I don't always get to choose what I work with.  I'd like to limit the caching above to only *static* assets, like .jpg, et. al.

In a python/django world, I could so something like

```
location /static/$ {
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
}
```

What I *think* I can do is

```
location ~ ^(*.jpg|*.png|*.gif)$ {
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /path/to/php$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
}
```

One more thing to mention.  The static file are not in a single `static` directory, rather mixed in with other directories..Hence the problem.

Will that work? Anyone have a good way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a separated location block for the static files:

```
location ~ ^/(static/) {
    root /path/to/the/static/dir;
    expires max;
}
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that the static files are not in a single directory.  They are mixed in with other content.  This is a Php App :)